# IAM User has access to S3 bucket, How to access that from Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a use case, where an IAM user in `Account-A` has access to files in an S3 bucket in `Account-B`.

I want to access these files from a Lambda function in `Account-A`.

Do I need to mention the credentials of IAM user while accessing the files? Is there any other alternative to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can associate an **IAM Role** with an AWS Lambda function. When the function runs, it uses the permissions associated with that IAM Role.

If your Lambda function is running in `Account-A` and it needs to access Amazon S3 objects in `Account-B`, there are two options:

- Option 1: Add a Bucket Policy to the bucket in `Account-B` that permits the IAM Role to access the objects, *or*
- Option 2: Add an IAM Role in `Account-B` that has access to the bucket and give permission for the Lambda function to **assume the role**. The Lambda function will then have temporary credentials to access the bucket.

The fact that you have an IAM User that has access to the objects in Amazon S3 does not help in this situation, since the Lambda function obtains its permissions from an IAM Role, not an IAM User.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a Lambda execution role in `Account-A` with any permissions the function needs, such as assuming a cross-account role in `Account-B`. In most situations if `Account-B` was willing to grant permissions to an IAM user in `Account-A`, they should be fine with providing an IAM role with similar permissions for you to assume. This is much safer than using an IAM access key as there are no permanent credentials to leak, only temporary credentials that will expire after a maximum of 12 hours.

If for whatever reason you can't get anything to be changed in `Account-B`, you could use your existing user directly. The simplest way to do this would involve hard coding the access key ID and secret access key into your Lambda, but this introduces a lot of problems from a secrets management perspective. Now if your code is leaked, the data in `Account-B`'s bucket would be compromised. AWS Secrets Manager is a decent native option for storing the keys outside of your code, but will require learning some API calls to incorporate it into your function.